# Make menu selection before while loop is done

Tags: javascript, php

I have a for I=1 to 5 loop with sleep for 5 seconds. 
How can I make a menu selection and continue to another page before the while loop is done.
Now when I chose the menu item the selection will take place when the while loop is done. Its about 30 seconds.
I have tried to put the while loop in an Iframe, and load it from another page, but it still first load next page when while loop is done.

From index page

```
        <link rel="icon" href= (./image/favicon.ico)/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./db/abcss.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./db/CSSnav.js"></script>

    </HEAD>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<?php
    include("top.php");
    include("IndexMenu.php");
?>


<div id="content75">

   <div id="h4"> <br/><b><center>Velkommen til t</center></b>
   </div>

<div id="h3"><br/><center> text here. </center><br/><br/>

<iframe  src="./eventrul.php" name = "content_iframe"></iframe>

<?php
    include("Bund.php")
?>
</body>
</html>
```

From while loop page

```
if ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)){

    echo "<div id=\"event\">";
        while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data) and $i < 5){
            echo "<script>";
            echo "document.getElementById('event').innerHTML = \"\"";
            echo "</script>";
            echo "<div id=\"event_indhold\">";
            if ($info['type']==='Andet'){
               $info['type'] = $info['typeandet'];
            }
            if ($info['emne']==='Andet'){
               $info['emne'] = $info['emneandet'];
            }
     echo "<table><tr><td width = 30% > "." <B>Event nummer:    </B>"."</td>"
     . "<td colspan = 10>".$info['arrnr'].", Overskrift: ". $info['type']."</td></tr><br/>";
     if ($info['arrangoer']!= ""){
        echo "<tr><td colspan =10>"."  ".$info['arrangoer']."</td> </tr>";
     }

     ob_flush();
     flush();
     sleep(4);
     $i++;
     echo "</div>";
     }
     echo "<script>";
     echo "document.getElementById('event').innerHTML = \"\"";
     echo "</script>";
     echo "<div id=\"event_indhold\">";
     echo '<a href="EventVis.php"><font size="5px">Klikke her   for at se eventlisten  </a>';
     echo "</div>";
     echo "</div>";
     }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. I suggest you add your code, like it is always required and tell us exactly what is happening and, what should happen instead.

Comment: Could you be more clear (putting up your code perhaps?)

Comment: I have now added some of the code

Comment: Have just discovered: Its only in Chrome it's not working. Work fine in IE and FireFox

Comment: That's a bit wierd, since php is a server side language...

Comment: When you put your id tags, you don't use '' around the actual id, wich might be why chrome won't read it?

Comment: Try use ' instead of \"

Comment: Or try echo '<div id="event_indhold">';

Answer (score 0):

You could put a `break;` when you know you want to exit the loop. It will simply break it.

Comment: Can't put a break in the loop. It's an menu-selection from top menu I'll want to go directly to new page and thereby break the loop/while-true